# getting data from a SQLite database and display in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get data from an `SQLite DB` in which I was successful to add data to it.I am using a `databaseHelper` class to add data and any other queries that the app may require.For reference, this is how the class looks like [DataBaseHelper](https://github.com/mitchtabian/SaveReadWriteDeleteSQLite/blob/master/SaveAndDisplaySQL/app/src/main/java/com/tabian/saveanddisplaysql/DatabaseHelper.java).
This is how my getData method from the helper looks like:

```
public Cursor getBasicWorkoutInfo(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COL2 +", "+COL3+", "+COL4 +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return data;

}
```

The `"COL"` are just strings tags to names of the fields in the DB.
The the `recyclerView` uses an `arrayList` of a class workout I created this is how it looks like

```
public class Workout {

public String workoutName;
public String numberOfSets;
public String restBetweenSets;

}
```

On the `onCreate` method of the activity I've put a method that handles getting the data from the DB but after testing it out the app crashes and the debug console shows an error in the third line of while loop.

```
 Cursor data=mDatabaseHelper.getBasicWorkoutInfo();

    Workout work=new Workout();


    while(data.moveToNext()){


        work.workoutName=data.getString(1);
        work.numberOfSets= String.valueOf(data.getInt(2));
        work.restBetweenSets=data.getString(3);


    }

    sampleWorkout.add(work);



    if (sampleWorkout.isEmpty()){

        createTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else {

    workoutRecyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myWorkoutsRecyclerView);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    workoutRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    workoutRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    workoutRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mWorkAdapter = new WorkoutsRecyclerAdapter(sampleWorkout, getBaseContext());
    workoutRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWorkAdapter);


    }
```

What could be the problem in the loop and how can I fix this so I can be able to add the data efficiently  to the `recyclerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Since column indexes start with 0 in query

Change to :

```
    work.workoutName=data.getString(0);
    work.numberOfSets= String.valueOf(data.getInt(1));
    work.restBetweenSets=data.getString(2);
```

Instead

```
    work.workoutName=data.getString(1);
    work.numberOfSets= String.valueOf(data.getInt(2));
    work.restBetweenSets=data.getString(3);
```

This is the solution `datatypes` use your table data type

Comment: Hi R2R, thank you for answering my question.Sorry I forgot to point that  index 0 if for the ID column of the table. So it will get the ID not the workout name

Comment: SELECT "+COL2 +", "+COL3+", "+COL4 +" FROM " + TABLE_NAME  if u run this it will start COL2 =0,COL3=1,COL4 =2..Is it helpful...

Comment: Thank you very much It worked..it populated the recyclerview only problem is that now is that it is overwriting the the data that is already displayed in the recyclerview and not adding new items to the recyclerview

Comment: Please check how many items are there in database.Whenever your sending arraylist to list refresh

Comment: Oh that's notifyDataSetChaged() sorry i forgot. But thank you. You have helped me.